# [__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchos-2

I'm creating a iWatch app in which I need to display an array of images. I'm using `WCSession` to transfer the images from the iPhone. Here is the code I tried:

**InterfaceController.m**

```
- (void)willActivate {
    [super willActivate];

   if ([WCSession isSupported]) {

    WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
    session.delegate = self;
    [session activateSession];

    NSLog(@"WCSession is supported");
}

- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveApplicationContext:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)applicationContext {
    NSLog(@"%@", applicationContext);

    NSData *imageData = applicationContext[@"image"];
    UIImage *contactImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    _graphImage = [contactImage valueForKey:@"image"];
}
```

In my iPhone app, I have an array which stores the images in bytes. After executing the iWatch app, I'm getting the `NSData` value from my iPhone app. But the app terminates at `UIImage *contactImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];` with

> [__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

I googled this error but not able to find a solution in my case.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Means your `imageData` is actually an `NSArray`

Comment: If you're new, why not learn Swift? Type checking would make your code more safe and `as?` would have avoided a crash from such an error.

Comment: @dan yes actually the applicationContext  contains the response from iphone app. So imageData is actually an NSArray

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're getting this error because there is missplaced type -_graphImage = [contactImage valueForKey:@"image"]; - here your are sending valueForKey for image instance

Comment: then how can i set the value in _graphImage

Comment: i solved it.. i deleted this    UIImage *contactImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];  and set the NSData value directly to _graphImage.. it worked for me.. Thanks for your help @ Karaban

Comment: [_graphImage setImageData:imageData];